# On a Mac, how to mount the Ubuntu installation image and install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, virtualbox, mount

On a Mac, is there a way to mount the image downloaded from Ubuntu and install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?

I could download that image and burn it to a CD-R or DVD-R if at home using a PC, but I am at work and only have a Mac (and don't have blank DVD-Rs)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to burn it: just use the VirtualBox device manager and select "mount image"; then you choose the ISO and you're done.

**Virtual Device Manager - Ctrl+D**

[image: Virtual Device Manager - Ctrl+D]

**Add CD/DVD in the storage panel**

[image: Add CD/DVD in the storage panel]

**Choose the ISO to mount**

[image: Choose the ISO to mount]

**Mount the ISO in any Virtual Machine you want**

Comment: Nice with screenshots. Could've switched to english locale before taking them, but nevermind. Now, perhaps Jian Lin is missing the installation procedure explanation... Lots of screenshots to provide ;-)